# Perl, substitute hexa text by the corresponding chr-ed character

Tags: regex, perl, chr

I have a file which contains long lines made of text mixed with encoded character.

```
%255D%252C%2522actualPage%2522%253A1%252C%2522rowPerPage%2522%253A50%257D%255D
```

Each encoder character is `%25xx` where `xx` is the hexa value of the ascii char  (ex. `%2540 = @`)

I tried the folowing but w/o success

```
perl -pe 's/%25([0-9A-F](0-9A-F])/\x$1/' myfile.txt
perl -pe 's/%25([0-9A-F](0-9A-F])/chr($1)/' myfile.txt
```

Do you have any clue for me ?

TIA, Peyre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/%25([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/chr hex $1/ge' myfile.txt
```

output

```
],"actualPage":1,"rowPerPage":50}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you want is [`URI::Encode`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aEncode). It is a better idea to use a module for this than a regex.

```
perl -MURI::Encode -nle'$u=URI::Encode->new(); print $u->decode($u->decode($_));'
```

Output is this for your input string:

```
],"actualPage":1,"rowPerPage":50}]
```

As you'll notice, the string had to be decoded twice, because it had been encoded twice (`%25` is apparently the percent sign `%`). The interim output was

```
%5D%2C%22actualPage%22%3A1%2C%22rowPerPage%22%3A50%7D%5D
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -MURI::Escape -ne'print uri_unescape(uri_unescape($_))'
```